# Why collect2 return ld returned 1 exit status?

Tags: c++, qt5

I downloaded and installed qt5 on my Arch linux but when I start simple code from wiki it doesn`t work. What is wrong?

```
    hello.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel hello("Hello world!");

    hello.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

And the comand

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs Qt5Widgets) -fPIC -o hello.cpp
```

With output

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Typo: `... -fPIC -o hello.cpp` --> `... -fPIC -o hello hello.cpp`?

Comment: Yep, thanks. I forgot parameter.